# Показать минимальное значение в numericUpDown1 по событию radioButton1_CheckedChanged

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в c# vs2010 winforms по событию:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int yearNow = System.DateTime.Now.Year;
            numericUpDown1.Maximum = new System.Decimal(new int[] { 2030, 0, 0, 0 });
            numericUpDown1.Minimum = new System.Decimal(new int[] { yearNow, 0, 0, 0 });
        }
```

показывать минимальное значение года. Сейчас код выше срабатывает только один раз при запуске формы и при первом выборе radioButton1?

Comment: почему не использовать datePicture? и второе, что по вашему должен делать код приведённый выше ? нужно добавить `numericUpDown1.Value`

Comment: Спасибо большое за Вашу подсказку! Получилось так: dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy";
dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;